# Rails 3.2 Sinatra mounted app JSON Parse errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, sinatra

I have a sinatra app mounted inside a rails 3.2.12 app which accepts JSON posts. The problem is that I get an error when one of the strings contains an asterisk(*) or a harsh(#) symbol. These are required because a USSD service will push data to my end point wich will contain "*712#".

I am positive its got to do with the * and # since removing them seams to work without throwing

```
MultiJson::LoadError at /ussdpush/requests
==========================================

> 399: unexpected token at '{"Mobile": "233208183783",   "SessionId":"8883ba8b1e7348b8b566b4b3396575c2", "ServiceCode":"712", "Type": "Initiation", "Message":"*712#", "Operator":"vodafone”, "Sequence":1}]'
```

How can I gracefully parse this?

Thanks

Comment: Found the solution. There was an unprintable charater in the JSON payload.

Comment: When you find a solution, please answer your own question and accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. There was an unprintable character in the JSON payload.